# Replace character with another only if repeated and not part of a word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In Python3, the following code works to replace a string (two or more) of `*`'s with `x`'s.

```
import re
re.sub(r'\*(?=\*)|(?<=\*)\*', 'x', 'Replace this *** but not this *')
# 'Replace this xxx but not this *'
```

But what if I also want to exempt a string of `*`'s that are part of a "word" like the following? (I.e. the string is attached to one or more `[a-zA-Z]` characters.)

```
text = "Don't replace foo*** or **bar, either."
# unmodified text expected
```

How do I do this? I can probably match the exempted cases as well and use a replacement function to deal with them, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 7):

```
regex = r"\s\*{2,}[\s\n]"
```

This matches 2 or more `*` chars, surrounded by whitespace (or ended with a newline)

Call it maybe like this?

```
regex = r"\s\*{2,}[\s\n]"


def replacer(match):
    return 'x' * len(match.group())

re.sub(regex, replacer, your_string_here)
```

Comment: You gave me a good idea for the use of the replacer function, but your pattern, by including the spaces in the match, would seem to turn `this **** string` into `this******string`, which is not I want. It would also not replace `**** this string`, which I do want to replace. That said, I now have a solution that works thanks to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is inspired Danielle M.'s. This pattern below seems to give me what I want. The rest is the same as hers.

```
regex = r'(?<![a-zA-Z])\*{2,}(?![a-zA-Z])'
```